# unable to start frame animation

Tags: android, frame, android-animation

I'm making a lockscreen ,I want to show frame animation displaying battery charging but the animation is not displayed and all Logs are printed .I have tried starting animation using handler also but of no use . My code is very lengthy so i'm adding the relevant code below.

code in on create :

```
//battery charging animation
    animation = new AnimationDrawable();
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.charge5), 30);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.charge4), 30);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.charge3), 30);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.charge2), 30);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.charge1), 30);
    animation.setOneShot(false);//animation plays again
    battery_ImgView.setBackgroundDrawable(animation)
```

code in function which checks battery status

```
public  void SetBatteryIcon(View paramView, int paramInt,
        int plugged, int m) {

    int i=0;
    int p = m / 4;
    if (plugged == 0) {
        if (paramInt <= p)
            i = R.drawable.battery4;// 1 line
        else if (paramInt <= 2 * p && paramInt > p)
            i = R.drawable.battery3;// 2 line
        else if (paramInt <= 3 * p && paramInt > 2 * p)
            i = R.drawable.battery2;// 3line
        else
            i = R.drawable.battery1;// 4 line full 
    } else {//  charging

        Log.i("charging","anim");
        animation.start();


    }//else
    paramView.setBackgroundResource(i);
}
```

Comment: Should you do a ``return`` in ``else`` case? Otherwise you end up calling ``setBackgroundResource`` with ``i = 0``?

Answer (score 1):

Use below code for starting animation.

```
AnimationDrawable mAnimDrawable=(AnimationDrawable)battery_ImgView.getBackground();
mAnimDrawable.start();
```

let me know if it will works.